# What makes my menu horizontal?

Tags: jquery, html, css

what makes my menu horizontal? On mobile I want to have a vertical menu and I cant find what is it. [Here´s my web.](http://www.matmasar.wz.cz/kontakt.php) When window´s width is smaller than 800px 3 line menu is shown. After click on it there´s horizotal menu but not vertical.

Website isn´t in English, because I am Czech so sorry for potential mistakes I´have done.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it seems from your code.

you have in each of your `<li>` `float:right`

in the media query of `800px` just add the code to the `li{ float:none;}`

this should fix it, but if not, add also to the li `display: inline;`

Comment: Thanks....it works

Answer (score 0):

within styles.css, around line 177 you have this code

```
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}
```

Both of these are causing your menu to be horizontal. If I remove these rules, this is what it looks like
[image]